# How to use nautilus as root user ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nautilus

I'm rather new to ubuntu and linux in general, so bear with me. I'm trying to put abode flash on firefox manually, and to do so I think I need to copy and paste a few things into a certain folder that I need root access to. I'm running ubuntu 17.10.

I've tried:

```
 sudo nautilus
```

which gives me

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:1130): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

and

```
gksudo nautilus
```

which gives me a popup message which says
"unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file"

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can copy/paste the plugin into ~/.mozilla/<profile name>/Plugins instead. That doesn't require root access, and should work just as well.

Comment: "any help would be appreciated"  There is ZERO usage for nautilus with root. Use command line to do what you want. It is THE powertool for maintaining your system.